# Data Entry in List Error Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Error creating bean with name 'sumitgulati' defined in class path resource [SpringModule.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'lists' of bean class

Spring.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
  <bean id="sumitgulati" class="com.spring.first.ListClass">
    <!-- java.util.List -->
    <property name="lists">
      <list>
        <value>1</value>
        <value>2</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

ListClass.java

```
package com.spring.first;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListClass {
    private List<Integer> lists=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    @Override
   public String toString()
   {
       return lists.toString();
   }
   public List<Integer> getList()
   {
       return this.lists;
   }

    public void setList(ArrayList<Integer>lists)
   {
       this.lists=lists;
   }
}
```

above mentioned error is coming I am new to Spring Framework. Please help

Comment: You are trying to set property named `lists`, but the getters and setters for that property are named `getList()` and `setList()`. They should be named `getLists()` and `setLists()`.

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt thank you it worked :)